# It automatically deletes the <script> tag in the description section of the category

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried to use the category description to add schema to the categories, but it automatically deletes the  tag after saving it.

is there a way to prevent this in wordpress

[image]

after recording;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security fields like this tend to be sanitized to prevent random scripts from being injected.

You are better off using wp_enqueue_script or wp_head

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_head/

Using wp_enqueue_script you could check against the category and have it add it that way which also makes it so it only shows up within that/those categories.